# angular 6 ng-bootstrap typeahead multiple column results

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, typeahead

In an Angular 6 project I have used ng-bootstrap to create a typeahead, which returns an array of objects.

I would like to display the results in a multiple column format, with each column representing a property of the object.

In AngularJS, I was able to achieve this using the Angular UI Bootstrap typeahead directive as so:

```
<div class="typeahead-class">
    <input id="slipInfoFilter" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="vm.contractCertainty.SlipInfo" placeholder="Start typing to choose an Insured"
    typeahead="slipInfo as slipInfo.Insured.InsuredName for slipInfo in vm.getSlipInfos($viewValue)" typeahead-editable="false"
    typeahead-template-url="App/Features/ContractCertainty/SlipInfoList.html"/>
</div>
```

The template for the results was this:

```
<a>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <span ng-bind-html="match.model.Insured.InsuredName | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <span ng-bind-html="match.model.YearOfAccount"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <span ng-bind-html="match.model.Broker.BrokerName"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <span ng-bind-html="match.model.Cedant"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <span ng-bind-html="match.model.Layer"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <span ng-bind-html="match.model.Inception | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <span ng-bind-html="match.model.LeadDisplay"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <span ng-bind-html="match.model.RiskStatus"></span>
    </div>
```

And the result looked like this:

[image: Typeahead results]

I have not been able to replicate this in Angular 6 / ng-bootstrap. I replaced the ng-bind-html directive in my template with the new innerHTML directive but to no avail.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">


<a>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <span [innerHTML]="r.insured.name"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
      <span [innerHTML]="r.layer"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</ng-template>

<div class="typeahead-class">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="searchFailed" [(ngModel)]="dfRisk" [ngbTypeahead]="search" 
    placeholder="Find a risk" [resultTemplate]="rt" />
  <span *ngIf="searching">Searching...</span>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="searchFailed">No risks could be found.</div>
</div>
```

And here the results I am unhappy with:

[image: New typeahead]

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Why not use a material Data Table with filter? https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering

Comment: I think that the problem is that you're including a "<a>" in your template (try remove -You needn't it-) Moreover, try using class col-3 (not col-xs-3)

Comment: @Eliseo That worked! Please add that as an answer. Thanks.